# Email Field returns blank string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am using devise in my Rails3 application.The problem I am facing is the email field is being returned as a blank string after save.

```
    resource.save
    Rails.logger.info p resource
```

This returns me

```
#<User id: 1850, email: "", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$EZnvzTKpgYyN2K8I20vXBuk6OZ.XQ6gfOCbOUyfkDKx/...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, confirmation_token: "6e6c41315002a24cf63e4512ab94f693ef9d419218e1cbb9a2d...", confirmed_at: nil, confirmation_sent_at: "2015-07-02 04:49:23", unconfirmed_email: "anildiasdavis@gmail.com", company_code: "WNZQIFHN", partner_id: nil, partner_type: nil, super_admin_id: nil, super_admin_type: nil, device_token: nil, is_active: nil, is_disabled: false, total_session_time: "0:0:0", status: "pending", created_at: "2015-07-02 04:49:20", updated_at: "2015-07-02 04:49:20", doctor_id: nil, last_notified_offer_id: nil, is_deleted: false, remove_reason: nil, active_at: nil, deactivated_at: nil, was_disabled: false, is_first_menu_selection: true, is_default_filter: true>
```

But when I query the console it gives me the correct response.

```
#<User id: 1850, email: "anildiasdavis@gmail.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$EZnvzTKpgYyN2K8I20vXBuk6OZ.XQ6gfOCbOUyfkDKx/...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, confirmation_token: "6e6c41315002a24cf63e4512ab94f693ef9d419218e1cbb9a2d...", confirmed_at: nil, confirmation_sent_at: "2015-07-02 04:49:23", unconfirmed_email: "anildiasdavis@gmail.com", company_code: "WNZQIFHN", partner_id: nil, partner_type: nil, super_admin_id: nil, super_admin_type: nil, device_token: nil, is_active: nil, is_disabled: false, total_session_time: "0:0:0", status: "pending", created_at: "2015-07-02 04:49:20", updated_at: "2015-07-02 04:49:20", doctor_id: nil, last_notified_offer_id: nil, is_deleted: false, remove_reason: nil, active_at: nil, deactivated_at: nil, was_disabled: false, is_first_menu_selection: true, is_default_filter: true>
```

Why does this happen?Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: Can you check if there are any errors with `resource.errors` after `resource.save` ?

Comment: No there are no errors.Actually i tried doing this
if resource.save
   Rails.logger.info p resource
end
This also gives the same issue